# issue app recognizing phones screen size

Tags: android, layout

I  have setup multiple layouts and put them in their  layout-small Layout-normal large and  xlarge folders. I have established the supported screens in the manifest.   I am testing on an older phone with a small screen and the app seems to recognize the size of the phone because the layout is perfect.  I am also testing on a note 3 and the layout will not change when updating the file in my layout-large folder.  What am I missing?

Comment: You can also use `@dimen/image_size` for each screen size. I do this and it works just fine for me with different screen

Comment: So from my understanding, as long as the folders are setup and you have customized the xml filed inside the different folders, android should automatically choose the layout size that fits your phones screen. I have several different layouts and the only layout that changes the look on any size screen is the cml files inside layout-normal folder. How do I get the app to choose the other sizes as well

Comment: I have different `dimen` file setup for different folder and have the image in the `drawable` folder and Android being so efficient chooses the correct size based on the screen size. It's less headache to create different layout unless of course you are loading lots of images in which case it will be slow and it's best to use different image sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to correct the issue of the app not recognizing the different size screen was by renaming my layout folders. I renamed layout-small to layout-ldpi, layout-normal to layout-mdpi, layout-large to layout-hdpi, and layout-xlarge to layout-xhpdi. For more info on supporting multiple screens check out http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html